# Why do I get a 404 Not Found when trying to get server status?

Tags: apache-2.2

```
<Location /status>
    SetHandler server-status
    order deny,allow
    allow from all
</Location>
```

But when I visit `http://ip:port/status`,

a `404 Not Found` is reported, why?

Comment: Just for the heck of it, create an index.html file in that directory and see what happens.

Comment: @John Gardeniers,MUST that directory exist in the first place? I followed your advice but don't get anything different...

Comment: Obviously the directory must exist or you must always get a 404 for it because the server can't serve what isn't there. The reason I suggested creating the index file is because, depending on how your setup is configured, the lack of an index file may result in a 404 unless you specifically specify another file that does exist in your URL.

Comment: @John: For a `server-status`?  I've never had to have a physical file on disk for `server-status` to work.

Comment: @John Gardeniers,why is the file still required when it's handled by `SetHandler server-status`?

Answer (score 21):

This can also happen when you have a `.htaccess` file in the document root and that file contains a `RewriteRule`, as is common with CMS pretty URLs.

The explanation for this behaviour is as follows. The `<Location>` directives act first, but the handler is not called at this stage.  So then the `RewriteRule` sets a handler, eg to run a PHP script, so `SetHandler` has no effect in the end.

If this is the cause, find the `RewriteRule` that is causing the problem(*), and add before it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
```

This excludes the `server-status` URI from the `RewriteRule` in the same way that existing static files may be excluded. Of course what you use in place of `/server-status` must exactly match the `Location` chosen, which in the question is instead `/status`. (Tested on Apache 2.2.22 and Apache 2.4)

Addendum: also note that you can get a 403 trying to read the `server-status` if the `DocumentRoot` is not readable by the apache process at all, again because the server-status handler doesn't have a chance to work.

Addendum 2: if the `.htaccess` for the Apache default site is frequently overwritten, and the `/server-status` URL is necessary for eg Munin to work, then creating a `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>` stanza including the server-status handler may be administratively simplest.

Addendum 3(*): the `RewriteRule` that is causing the problem is potentially anything that matches the string `/server-status`. This may be identifiable because the first parameter will match anything, for example beginning `RewriteRule .` where the `.` will match any character, or `^(.*)`, or otherwise is catching the URI such as `.*\bstatus$`. You may also identify it because it deliberately excludes existing files with `!-f`.

For example, if WordPress is the main site and you want `/server-status` to appear on it, and for some reason Addendum 2 above is not applicable, you may want to insert an extra `RewriteCond` as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

However, it probably does no harm before any `RewriteRule`.

Comment: It worked on Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS7).

Comment: It was the case on my Apache 2.4.10 on Debian too. THANKS!

Comment: The Apache documents stipulate that _you need to have a `RewriteEngine on` directive for each virtual host in which you wish to use rewrite rules_.  I think this means I would need to configure the above `RewriteCond` once for each `RewriteRule`.  So I chose to create a `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>` as suggested in _Addendum 2_ above to deal with multiple `RewriteRules`.  And it seems to be working!

Comment: @CODE-REaD The mention of `RewriteEngine` is a red herring. It must already be `on` for the rule to be interfering with `/server-status`.

I didn't say how to identify the rule "that is causing the problem" though, and maybe I should have, to save adding the line for each rule: the rule is probably a generic one where the first parameter is `.` or `.*` and may be preceded by other `RewriteCond` directives such as excluding a file `!-f`.

Comment: thank you, the culprit was htaccess

Comment: thank you for the specifics for wordpress too

Comment: Also, on wordpress, it might be needed to remove write permissions from .htaccess file as wordpress keeps updating it with original content.

Comment: @JanJůna Removing write permissions from .htaccess is one solution.  Mine was my Addendum 2. Kirrus's solution would also survive updates, although in my experience it doesn't always work.

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be that you didn't load the status module - Can you confirm it ?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Because you've misconfigured something.  What do your logs say about the cause of the 404?  My first guess would be that `ip:port` isn't a valid vhost (or at least not valid for the vhost you've put the `<Location /status>` in, anyway), and it's probably dropping back to the default vhost.  The error logs will make mention of irrational paths you didn't configure if that's the case.  Other error log messages will mean different things, which is why it's so important to check them.

Comment: The log also says `File does not exist`

Comment: Of course it does, that's why you got a 404.  But what *else* does it say?

Comment: It doesn't say anything else.

Comment: At the very least, it will tell you which file does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

https://serverfault.com/a/388457/ had the answer for me. Needed to actively block the call rather than trying to find/block every .htaccess RewriteRule interfering with request handling.

I added:

`RewriteRule ^/server-status - [L]`

Into the location block, and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

- you do not need to configure a directory or path or index file
- are you trying a different port? you shouldn't be port 80

the docs are:

```
<Location /server-status>
SetHandler server-status
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Locaton>
```

your location differs, I would not think it should matter, but try your location as /server-status instead of just /status.

However - I think Spud is right. you have not loaded that module.

-sean

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/), as I am for development, make a note of the following:

- The `httpd-info.conf` file located at `wamp\bin\apache\apache[version]\conf\extra` contains relevant `<Location>` configuration:

  `<Location /server-status>
      SetHandler server-status
      #Require host .example.com
      #Require ip 127
  </Location>`
- This file may or may not actually be included in your Apache configuration. Look for the following line in your `httpd.conf` file and make sure it is uncommented:

  `Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf`

In my case, the main problem was the latter: the line was commented by default and thus `httpd-info.conf` wasn't even loading.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using mod_rewrite and vhost configuration you need to add a blank vhost entry at the top of the vhost configuration file e.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you can access it via the server IP address e.g. ip_address/server-status

Comment: Won't you also need a `SetHandler server-status` in that vhost?